# Docker swarm бесконечная загрузка

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Пробую делать всё по документации: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/

1. Создаю ноду docker swarm init
2. Стартую регистр как сервис: docker service create --name registry --publish published=5000,target=5000 registry:2
   Всё успешно срабатывает, в списке сервисов висит
   Но когда начинаю проверять через curl localhost:5000, то в ответ ничего, бесконечная загрузка.
   Это особенность swarm или в чем может быть дело?

---

Если писать конкретно ip(127.0.0.1), то всё работает